# Real World CNC Machining Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need to re-find center on a circle. In our tool room a tool maker milled an annulus with a 4 hole pattern. The holes were milled in a square, each equidistant from the center of the annulus. The part was removed from the machine and pins were installed into the holes. Then returned to the machine for more work.

[image]

In order to re-find the center the tool maker puts a dial indicator in the spindle and moves the spindle close to the center of the part and checks the pins with the indicator. The indicator will tell him the relative distance each pin is from the center of the spindle. in other words the indicator tip is some at some arbitrary radius from the center of the spindle and when it moves past a pin the dial shows how much closer the pin is to center than the neutral position of the tip.

Known:

- The radius of the annulus, pin pattern and pins
- The origin of the coordinate system is within the annulus
- The origin of the coordinate system is defined by the axis of the spindle/indicator.
- The difference, radially, between a radius of constant, but arbitrary length and the distance from the pins and the origin of the coordinate system.

Unknown

- The angle of the square hole pattern to the coordinate system
- Location of the center of the annulus relative to the coordinate system.

Assumptions:

- The parts are machined to perfect tolerances

Looking for:

- An equation that describes the center of the annulus

Update:

Please forgive the hand drawn diagram (if anyone has a recommendation for an easy way to draw pretty diagrams on the computer, please let me know).

Here is a drawing of how I visualize the problem.

R is the arbitrary, unknown radius of the indicator centered at the origin.

$\delta_A$ (etc.) is the measurement from the indicator. Therefor, point A (the closest point of the pin to the center) is at a distance of R-$\delta_A$ from the center, with an unknown angle $\theta_A$

Square ABCD is of known size but not known position, so I cannot simply find it's center. AB=BC=CD=AD, AC=BD; known: length AC

Looking for the position of center point c (sorry about any ambiguity around pin C and center point c)

[image]

Comment: Could you rephrase that in a more mathematical way? I'm not sure I understood what you are about.

Comment: Why not just find the center of the square? Eg, fit a couple of L-squares snugly around the four pins to make a square frame, then "draw" the diagonals of that frame to cross at the center.

Comment: @Blue - Thank you for your suggestion. The position of the pins is unknown. I hope my update is more clear.

Comment: @GeordieCampbell: *"The position of the pins is unknown"* Hmm ... You also mention in your update that, say, $\theta_A$ (the direction of one pin from the indicator-center) is "unknown". If you don't know the direction of any pin from indicator-center, then you can't know in which direction the annulus-center lies. Eg, suppose the indicator-center is "at" pin $A$: your measurements will tell you that the center is distance $r$ *toward* pin $C$ (ie, *away from* $A$). But with no directional information, you can't know which way that is. You need at least one pin direction (eg, $\theta_A$).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let (known) common length $CA_k=\rho$.

Let $r$ be the length and $\theta$ the polar angle of $\vec{OC}$.

Let $\rho$ be the length and $\alpha$ the polar angle of $\vec{CA_4}$.

With the other notations of the figure, we can write 4 equations with 3 unknowns, each one being  the cosine law applied to one of the four triangles with "a" red, "a" blue and "the" green arrow :

$$OA_k^2=OC^2+CA_k^2-2 OC.CA_k \cos(...)$$

i.e.,

$$\color{blue}{\gamma_k}^2=\color{green}{r}^2+\color{red}{\rho}^2-2 r \rho \cos(\theta+\alpha+k \pi/2), \ \ \ \ k=1,2,3,4,$$

giving rise to a system of four equations with three unknowns $r,\theta$ and $R$:

$$\begin{cases}
k=1: \ \ &(R-\delta_1)^2=\gamma_1^2&=&r^2+\rho^2+2 r \rho \sin(\theta)\\
k=2: \ \ &(R-\delta_2)^2=\gamma_2^2&=&r^2+\rho^2+2 r \rho \cos(\theta)\\
k=3: \ \ &(R-\delta_3)^2=\gamma_3^2&=&r^2+\rho^2-2 r \rho \sin(\theta)\\
k=3: \ \ &(R-\delta_4)^2=\gamma_4^2&=&r^2+\rho^2-2 r \rho \cos(\theta)
\end{cases}$$

which looks tractable ; for example

$$\frac{Eq. 1-Eq. 3}{Eq. 2-Eq. 4} \iff \tan \theta = \frac{\gamma_1^2-\gamma_3^2}{\gamma_2^2-\gamma_4^2}$$

connecting in fact angle $\theta$ and radius $R$.

Anyway, there is a good hope that this system having less unknowns than equations is solvable...

I stop there and ask you if it is the kind of development you wanted or not, or not exactly...

Comment: Waiting for your comments.

Comment: Jean, thank you for your response. I hope my update clarifies your questions. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Jean, this looks promising. I did try to put the four equations above in Wolfram Alpha's system of equations solver with some realistic values for $\delta_k$ (0.005mm, 0.010mm, 0.007mm, 0.003mm) and $\rho$ (25mm). Unfortunately, it could not find a solution. I can provide a screenshot of the attempt if it will help.

Comment: @Geordie It's classical : we have an overdermined system (4 equations with 3 unknowns). I advise you in a first step to use only the three first equations. You should get at least a solution or a list of solutions $S_1$. Then replace the third equation by the fourth ; you will get another list of solutions $S_2$. One of the solutions $S_1$ should be close to another in $S_2$. Of course, a neater way would be to look for a "least squares solutions" but the step you are involved in at present is very important in order to check the equations.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I have ran all four sets of three equations with a range of r values of approximately 20% (~0.00316 to ~0.00412). Practically speaking this is close enough, the machine has a hard time making discrete movements at the single micron level).

Wolfram is reporting values of $\theta$ in terms of n and with long calculations, which I understand the reason, but it will take me quite some time to parse.

Comment: Good news. It is maybe time to consider a global "mean squares solution". I will think about it.

Comment: I must admit I am starting to get out of my depth with the suggestion of the least squares approach. I remember hearing the term in school, and I am sure I spent countless hours practicing it. But, I have not used it since, and frankly not sure which book to even go look in. Do you think there is value in pursuing this method or will the system of equations method be close enough?

Comment: I am sure that the least square approach is definitively an important improvement because it drives us automatically to the best tradeoff. I look at it in the coming 24 hours.